# using (post) request from frontend to trigger Django script on backend

Tags: reactjs, django, request, backend, redux-toolkit

Pretty new to Django (and fullstack), thanks for help!

**Objective:**
My basic need is to be able to have React (or any frontend) communicate/trigger a django script from within frontend, (and eventually get the results back into frontend after the script runs). I have created the following code to create this utility, if you have a totally different way to achieve this objective, feel free to inform me regardless of code below.

**Approach:**
I THINK I need to structure the python script in views.py and have it trigger when it receives a post/get request (because each view has a url) and then send the data to the source of the request.

I tried using @require_POST by importing django.views.decorators.http. From my understanding this means it will ONLY except post requests, and run if the trigger is a post request, but haven't gotten it to work (404 error)

I also have a working django restapi via restapi_framework (which I need for other purposes) and I have made successful get requests to it. I am happy to use this part of the app/views if it'll help me.

(parts of) **my Code:** I am using react/redux redux toolkit on the frontend, so here is my thunk inside slice (unless I miswrote thunk, consider this a basic post request to url):

```
export const postRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  'slice/postRequest',
  async post => {
    const response = await client.post('URL', {slice: post})
    return response.slice
  }
)

export const slice = createSlice({
  name:'slice',
  initialState,
  reducers:{
  //reducers
  }
});
```

here would be the request itself:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {postRequest} from './slice'

const Component = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  dispatch(postRequest({data})

  return(null)
}
```

the url works when I go to it in my webbrowser, and a similar POST requests (thunk) to a npx json-server produces a post. But when I do a POST request to that url (from any of the three views below), it is rejected and throws a 404 error. My thinking was that I had not programmed it to receive a post request.

Here is the view.py file (with various attempts and ideas):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

#this tests to make sure urls/views are set up correct, and going to the url I always see 'test'
def option1(request):
  return HttpResponse('test')

def option2(request):
  def test = response.POST
  return HttpResponse('hello', test)

@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def option3(request):
  def test=response.POST
  def test2=request_response
  log.info(test, test2)
  return HttpResponse(test, test2)
```

Anyone have ideas how to help react communicate with Django so I can run python scripts when needed? this was the intention behind the React frontend/Django backend, but after some work on the app, this functionality remains lost on me. Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE** Here are my error messages:

Inside devtools:

```
main.js:2 POST https://URL/ 404
main.js:2 dispatching 
{type: "slice/postRequest/rejected", payload: undefined, meta: {…}, error: {…}}
error: {message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"}
meta: {arg: {…}, requestId: "Pi3VssbXU5DMTMscafAYb", rejectedWithValue: false, requestStatus: "rejected", aborted: false, …}
payload: undefined
type: "slice/postRequest /rejected"
```

on the log it just says:
[TIME] POST request URL has 404 N975

Comment: Not sure why you are using `def` in your views. Can you also post the error you get from the back-end?

Comment: 1. you think I should use class?
2. I posted the dev tools console message and the message on the log, is this what you Meant? thanks for the questions!

Comment: For 1) I should've been more clear. I meant why use `def test = response.POST` as opposed to just `test = request.POST`. Also, note I am using `request.POST` since the post request is attached to this object. For 2) I am not familiar with react at all but the error indicates that your front-end expects JSON but note that `HttpResponse` returns `bytes`. So maybe use `JsonResponse`?

Comment: It is my understanding now, that I should really just use the rest api to communicate from the frontend into the backend. Then I can also use some of the serializer functions to help with the requests as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working.

I had to use an Api_view decorator, and then conditional logic for if request.method = 'POST': etc... inside there I can import an external module(script) have it make a return, and then put that in the return inside views.py. If I want my return to involve the rest api, than obviously I need to make requests to the rest api views.

the code above is far far from functional. I did this on the server and not sure how to copy and paste off the server :/ so sorry I cannot post code to explain. It really isn't too complicated though.